# if else statement in yacc double execution

Tags: compilation, bison, yacc, compiler-construction

how do we implement if else in yacc ?

i tried this

```
|IF log THEN AffectationI ELSE AffectationI {if ($2) $$=$4; else $$=$6;}
```

but the $4 and $6 both execute at the same time

knowing that

> `AffectationI` is equal to Var=3

Comment: The value on the stack corresponding to `$4` (for example) was created when the first `AffectationI` was reduced (which is long before the second one was reduced). If you don't want that to happen, you need to rethink your semantic actions. Probably you want to build a parse tree rather than evaluate as you go.

Comment: any idea how to do that ? since we are behind and we didn't study semantic analysis

Answer (score 1):

yacc generates a parser, not a general program evaluator, so if you want to execute the program you're parsing, you need to implement something that can do that.  The simplest is to have your parser generate a tree an not evaluate anything, and then have a separate evaulator that "executes" the code in the tree by traversing it.  That way you can readily skip parts of the tree that should not be executed -- or repeatedly traverse parts of the tree that can be evaluated mulitple times, like loops.

Alternatively, you can have a global "condition" flag that controls whether things should be executed or not and manipulate that in your actions.  With this approach an if statement becomes something like:

```
statement:
    IF expression
        { $$ = condition_flag; // save the previous condition
          if (condition_flag) condition_flag = $2; }
    THEN statement_list
        { if ($3) condition_flag = !condition_flag; }
    ELSE statement_list
        { condition_flag = $3; } // restore previous condition
```